# Acr.UserDialogs alerts are skipped

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I think this has something to do with my async tasks within my method but I don't get why **one** of my three `Alert`s is shown and the others are not.

The one at the end of my if condition is shown and I want the user to commit the first `Alert` and then it shall go on.

Do you have an idea?

```
async void CreateInitialTxts()
    {
        if (InternetConnectionExists)
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("txt", "txt", "txt");

            var dataDevices = await downloadDevices.GetDevicesTxt();
            fileHandler.CreateTxt("devices.txt", dataDevices);
            var dataGasStations = await downloadGasStations.GetGasStationsTxt();
            fileHandler.CreateTxt("gasstations.txt", dataGasStations);
            fileHandler.CreateTxt("initialsync.txt", "false");

            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("txt", "txt", "txt");
        }
        else
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("txt", "txt", "txt");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `UserDialogs.Instance.Alert` inside `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`:

```cs
void DisplayDialog(String title, String message, String buttonText)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(title: title, message: message, okText: buttonText));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems in the shared code:

1. `async void CreateInitialTxts()` - never return a `void` from an async method, but `Task` or `Task<T>`. There are plenty of related threads here on SO and [articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) explaining that. In short, it is a bad practice since it might be tricky to catch an exception.
2. Replace the `UserDialogs.Instance.Alert` with `UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync` and await it. You may also consider a `Prompt` instead of `Alert` if you want to let the user to approve the upcoming action.
3. `UserDialogs.Instance.Alert` this is a tight coupling, consider wrapping the necessary functionality by an interface and use that interface instead of a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you could show the second Dialgo after click "Ok" of the first Dialog,like this :

```
  if (InternetConnectionExists)
    {
        //Create an AlertConfig
        var  config = new AlertConfig();
        config.Message = "txt";
        config.Title = "txt";
        config.OkText = "txt";

        //create action of "ok"
        config.OnAction += Show_Dialog2;
        UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(config);          

    }
    else
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("txt", "txt", "txt");
    }
```

when click "ok" of the first Dialog,show the second Dialog :

```
  private void Show_Dialog2()
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("txt", "txt", "txt");
    }
```